# Warning: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: Extra content at the end of the document

Tags: php, html, ajax, xml, dom

Hi I'm trying to append data into an existing file if not make a new file and save it.
Instead my code saves data for one time. next data set just overwrites the first.
  Please Help me to figure out what Im doing wrong....

After the comments I have changed the code and now I end up with
**Warning: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: Extra content at the end of the document in**

```
    function toXml($reg)
    {

        $xmlFile = "customers.xml";
        $doc = new DomDocument('1.0');
        $doc->load( $xmlFile);

        $cusCart = $doc -> createElement('cusCart');
        //$cusCart = $doc->appendChild($cusCart);

        foreach ($reg as $item => $val )

        {
            $customer = $doc->createElement('customer');
            $customer = $cusCart->appendChild($customer);

            $cusId = $doc->createElement('cusId');
            $cusId = $customer->appendChild($cusId);
            $value = $doc->createTextNode($item);
            $value = $cusId->appendChild($value);


            $fName = $doc->createElement('fName');
            $fName = $customer->appendChild($fName);
            $value1 = $doc->createTextNode($val["fName"]);
            $value1 = $fName->appendChild($value1);

            $lName = $doc->createElement('lName');
            $lName = $customer->appendChild($lName);
            $value2 = $doc->createTextNode($val["lName"]);
            $value2 = $lName->appendChild($value2);

            $phone = $doc->createElement('phone');
            $phone = $customer->appendChild($phone);
            $value3 = $doc->createTextNode($val["phone"]);
            $value3 = $phone->appendChild($value3);


            $email = $doc->createElement('email');
            $email = $customer->appendChild($email);
            $value4 = $doc->createTextNode($val["email"]);
            $value4 = $email->appendChild($value4);


            $pwd = $doc->createElement('pw');
            $pwd = $customer->appendChild($pwd);
            $value5 = $doc->createTextNode($val["pw"]);
            $value5 = $pwd->appendChild($value5);


        }

        $cusCart = $doc->appendChild($cusCart);     
        $doc->save($xmlFile);

        $strXml = $doc->saveXML();
        echo("<br>----- DATA RECOREDED!!! ----");

        return $strXml;
    }
```

Comment: The instructions in your if/else (file_exists('cusXML.xml')) are both the same. Why do that?

Comment: I'm trying to save the data in to the file if the file doesn't exists...

Comment: Your'e saying "if the file does not exist do this else do exactly the same thing"

Comment: You need a better error handling on the line of code where you load the XML into DOMDocument. Fix that location first, deal with the case that loading did fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was causing becaues of badly formatted xml file.
My xml file is

```
<cusCart> <customer> <cusid>...</cusid> </customer> </cusCart>
```

On my code Im calling  (root element)each time. so each time I append 
`<cusCart> <customer> <cusid>...</cusid> </customer> </cusCart><cusCart> <customer> <cusid>...</cusid> </customer> </cusCart>` happens

Instead I have to call root once to append `<customer> <cusid>...</cusid> </customer><customer> <cusid>...</cusid> </customer>` Thanks for the tips anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Child nodes and attributes should be added to a node, before appending it to its parent. Please try the following

```
function toXml($reg){
    $doc = new DomDocument('1.0');
    $doc->load( 'cusXML.xml');

    $cusCart = $doc -> createElement('cusCart');
    foreach ($reg as $item => $val )
    {
        $customer = $doc->createElement('customer');

        // Create cusId node
        $cusId = $doc->createElement('cusId');
        $value = $doc->createTextNode($item);
        $value = $cusId->appendChild($value);
        $cusId = $customer->appendChild($cusId);

        // Create pw node
        $pwd = $doc->createElement('pw');
        $value5 = $doc->createTextNode($val["pw"]);
        $value5 = $pwd->appendChild($value5);
        $pwd = $customer->appendChild($pwd);

        $customer = $cusCart->appendChild($customer);
    }

    $cusCart = $doc->appendChild($cusCart);

    if(file_exists('cusXML.xml')) { $doc->save("cusXML.xml"); }
    else{ $doc->save("cusXML.xml"); }

    $strXml = $doc->saveXML();
    echo("<br>----- DATA RECOREDED!!! ----");
    return $strXml;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your code, I have done few changes and now I end up with               Warning: DOMDocument::load() [domdocument.load]: Extra content at the end of the document

Comment: What do you see if you dump the XML string?

Answer (score 0):

You may have an additional `text` or `tag` after the end of XML Document. Like

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<document>
    <article>sample</article>
</document>
</xml>
```

So just remove other texts after `root` element. In above example, root element is `</document>` and other text or element is `</xml>`.

As you're generating XML dynamically, so check first your XML before further processing and identify additional text after root element is ended.